# Correct way to manually construct ember component and allow actions to be picked up by controller

Tags: ember.js

I have a component addon project and I want to allow users to supply their own sub component.  This is wrapping a JQuery library so I don't have the possibility of using traditional ember concepts such as {{#each}} or the {{component}} helper.  For this reason I need to create the component in JS code.

User will supply an itemComponent to my-component;

controller

```
import customUserComponent from './custom-user-component'

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    customUserComponent
})
```

template

```
{{my-component itemComponent=customUserComponent}}
```

The itemComponent is passed to the JQuery library and created when needed by the library.  It expects the raw HTML so I need to return item.element.  I Have to create it manually as follows.

```
      suggestion: function(model) {
        const item = this.get('itemComponent').create({
          model: model
        }).createElement();
        return item.element;
      },
```

The component the user supplies could have buttons and ember {{actions}} in it.  How can I force the action to be picked up by the controller and not swallowed by `my-component`?  Is there an official way of doing this?

Comment: If the library requires the raw html, this is going to be extremely difficult, because that html is going to change over time.

Comment: It does, but it is very short lived.  The components renders suggestions from an ajax search a the user types.  So the component lifetime might be 5 seconds or so.

Comment: Hmmm... have you tried just using ember-cli-auto-complete?

Comment: Well actually I am the author of [this](https://github.com/aupac/ember-aupac-typeahead) addon.  A user has asked me to add [this](https://github.com/aupac/ember-aupac-typeahead/issues/12) feature.